# Why is DD taking so long?

Tags: dd

Background:
I have an 8-disk Network Attached Storage device. I've been having issues with it where the hard drives fail on a regular basis. I figured out what the problem is with this: firmware issues with Seagate HDDs being compatible with my QNAP. So I need to update the firmware on each of the 8 HDDs.  Each of the HDDs are 3TB in size.  Previously, when one failed, I told the NAS to rebuild it (since I used RAID 5), and it took somewhere between 42-44 hours to do.

Current Problem:
I am using DD to capture an image of one of the 3TB HDDs.  It is plugged into my other laptop via eSATA and the drive I am writing to is on a USB 3.0 connection.  When I first started the image, I did the math to figure out how much time would be needed to finish.  My calculations based on how long DD was running (via PS) and how much data had been written (via LS), it looked to be the same (42-44 hours).  However, this process has been going on for almost a week. At the rate it ACTUALLY goes (realtime) it will take an entire week (7d to the hour exactly) for this to finish.

Double-checking:
Right now, we're at 6d of DD running its course.  When I type `ps -ef | fgrep DISK1` I get the following:

`root      6444  6388 36 Jan12 pts/0    2-04:54:14 dd if=/dev/sde of=/media/4TB/DISK1.raw`

PS claims that this has only been running for 2d 4h, when in reality, it's been running for over 6d.

My questions:
Why is this?  How can I fix it?  Could it be a multi-threading issue (or lack of multi-threading I mean)?  I did find that Ubuntu was suspending the OS when I closed the lid of the laptop, so I changed that very early on in the process so now it doesn't sleep, but it's still taking "forever".

Comment: Try specifying block size: bs=32M . The default is 512 bytes. Try up and down. It depends on the hardware..

Comment: I believe `ps` reports the CPU time consumed by `dd`, not the actual time it has run. As @Sneetsher mentioned, your `dd` command does not seem to have specified the block size. For most modern disks, 512 bytes is far too low to be optimal. You can also send a `USR1` signal to the running dd process to find out the progress: `kill -USR1 6444`.

Comment: That's what I figured, @yjwong :(

Comment: So, an update: it finished and I tried to fix my NAS and everything I tried didn't work, so now I have to create another image. I have downloaded PV to use with DD and I am trying the bs=32M that @Sneetsher suggested. So far, it is saying it will take around 26 hours, which is faster than it took for the NAS to rebuild a RAID disk. Kudos!

Comment: How did it pass?

Comment: It didn't.  Looks like the dd worked, but the NAS is being finnicky and won't recognize the copy.  I am going to have to figure something else out.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this QA while researching options for my own disappointing Seagate HDDs. You've got `pv`, which operates like `cat` with additional bonus of progress reporting. [`cat` is faster than `dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492). Even with optimal block size in `dd`, `cat` is 30MB/sec+ faster.

I have `pv /dev/sdd > /dev/sdc` running and its speed varies from 170MB/sec to 195MB/sec. On my 3TB drive, that's supposed to be 4.3 hours. Concurrently, I'm runniung `cat /dev/sdb > /dev/sda` in another terminal. When I queried it's speed via `cat /proc/[pid]/io`, I calculated it to be roughly 180MB/sec.

This simultaneous cloning is working using the motherboard RAID in JBoD mode.